# Elasticsearch - How to secure (lock) mapping from accidental deletion

Tags: elasticsearch

let us say here is the mapping

localhost:9200/index/mapping

now

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/index/mapping/id'
```

this will delete the record with the given id

but if we miss the /id by mistake
that is

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/index/mapping'
```

then elasticsearch will delete the mapping completely.

How to avoid this? is there any configuration option available in elasticsearch to lock the mapping from deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configuration setting, index setting, or map setting that will prevent disallow this operation.